# How to disable MySQL comments for InnoDB with foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, comments, innodb

For some time I noticed that MySQL would append comments to InnoDB tables that have foreign keys defined. It looks like this:

`InnoDB free: 0 kB; (event_id) REFER events(event_id) ON U...`

In order to display my table description correctly, I have to parse string and split it by semicolon. 
It is not big deal in general, however it's quite annoying to see this messages all the time in Database GUI.

I went through stackoverflow and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370473/why-does-mysql-add-a-comment-to-innodb-tables) which was not very handy in my case, so I'm wandering is it possible to disable this behaviour/bug?

UPDATE: MySQL version installed on hosting provider servers is 5.0.77

Comment: In general using `information_schema` views gives you more flexibility when fetching information about database objects.

Comment: I agree but result is still the same, MySQL adds this annoying comments to table description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this question in MySQL official forum. It seems that MySQL engineers know the problem but aren't fixing it. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,49710,49710#msg-49710

> I'm not sure I'm in the position to
>   negotiate a change in the InnoDB
>   storage engine, however if you ask me
>   as a user and a MySQL developer I'd
>   say: yes, change this as soon as you
>   can. The free space info does not
>   belong in the table comment.  .. Mike
>   Lischke, Senior Software Engineer
>   MySQL Developer Tools  Oracle
>   Corporation, www.oracle.com ..

-

> some
>   applications will break when we move
>   the info from the comment to
>   Data_free. And users will need to
>   learn a new way to check the free
>   space. Thus, the change can only take
>   place in a new major version. Heikki 
>   Oracle Corp./Innobase Oy  InnoDB -
>   transactions, row level locking, and
>   foreign keys for MySQL